# IE9 prototype mouseover and mouseout mismatch

Tags: internet-explorer-9, prototypejs, mouseover

I'm facing a strange behaviour by IE9 dealing with a prototype script.
Here I'm setting two different opacity styles depending on mouseover / out:

```
window.onload = function(){
var freccia1 = $($$('.next_button')[0]);
freccia1.setStyle({opacity: '0.20'});       
freccia1.setStyle({filter: 'alpha(opacity=20)'});   
var freccia2 = $($$('.previous_button')[0]);
freccia2.setStyle({opacity: '0.20'});       
freccia2.setStyle({filter: 'alpha(opacity=20)'});
}
```

This is working fine in all browsers, including previous IE versions, nut not in IE9 which doesn't low the opacity..its console returns me:
*Not possible to get the property 'setStyle' value: object null or undefined*


does anyone know why ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Prototype, you might as well use as much functionality as it offers since it takes browser compatibility into consideration so you don't have to.

Try this (untested):

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    [$$('.next_button')[0], $$('.previous_button')[0]].each(function(ele) {
        $(ele).setStyle({
            opacity: '0.20',
            filter: 'alpha(opacity=20)'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but your code returns me: "$(ele).setStyle is undefined"...

Comment: @asnothingelse are you sure `$$('.next_button')[0]` and `$$('.previous_button')[0]` exist?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of prototype you are running. I ran into a similar problem that may be similar on one of my pages using prototype 1.5.0 (please don't judge). In 1.5.0 the setStyle and getStyle functions do a browser check for IE specifically when dealing with opacity/alpha(opacity).

```
/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

In my case, setStyle calls getStyle('filter').replace(). Unfortunately getStyle('filter') returns null with IE9 so .replace throws an exception.

Some relevant notes from the IE team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/08/17/ie9-opacity-and-alpha.aspx